# b is not bolding text to 900 per my css

Tags: css

The messy code comes from pasting in from WORD.  I have resolved most of the issue with inline styling but I can't figure out how to get the  to be font-weight:900;

```
<p>
<span style="color: #000000;">
<span style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', serif;">
<span>
<b>Intensity of Service</b>
</span></span> </span></p>
```

Here is the example page: https://www.racmonitor.com/word

"Intensity of Service" should be font-weight:900 but is staying at 300.

Comment: you don't have the bold font

Comment: Bold is 700 btw and for me it works with the fallback font (as I don't have Lucida Grande)

Comment: it must be the font.  Thanks

Comment: Have you been changing the webpage in the meantime? Its source does not look like your example here.

Comment: yes, I resolved it.  This question can be deleted.